Alert dialog before in-app review launch in Android? Is that accepted?
I am implementing an in-app review flow in Android using Google's API.
I want to know if it is acceptable if I want to have an AlertDialog that is displayed that asks user if they like the app or not and if they say YES, then only I launch the review flow.
